# Refreshing page in JavaScript when another page is loaded

Tags: javascript, php

Currently I am working on one project, that is a little complicated for my programming capabilities, so the general idea might be wrong. I need to do just one more thing to make everything functionable. I am using local storage in order to temporarily save data from page1.php and after that, display data on page2.php. But when I load page2.php, there is no data because I did not load page1.php first (it is needed to send data to local storage).
The user for his needs does not have to load page1.php first and that is a problem.
Is there any way to reload page1.php when any other page is loaded in order to save data on local storage. In JavaScript or PHP. Thanks in advance.

I tried some manipulations with reload() function, but did not find any solution.

Comment: I just want to know is this achievable. If it's not, I need to do a lot of changes to my code.

Comment: If the user doesn't want to visit page1, you can't exactly force them to. But maybe page2 should check first if the data exists in localstorage, and if it doesn't, then refuse to continue until the user goes and loads page1. Or maybe there is a way for it to do (some of) the work without that data? Or maybe you can do all the functionality in one page instead of 2?? I don't know, we don't have the context about what the data is, what it's used for or how important it is. We can't suggest an implementation without a clear specification, really.

Comment: What you could do is check `localStorage` for the data you require on `page2.php` and if it is not present, use `window.location.assign('page1.php')` to redirect the user. You could also achieve the same using PHP sessions.

Comment: I think it would help if you would demonstrate what kind of data is provided on page 1 and what the user needs on page 2. There might be a better system for this.

Comment: what tasks/actions/interactions on `page1` cause the required data to be stored in `localStorage`? In what way is this data dependant upon the actual user?